# How to remove an element at an index?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying remove an object at index.

This is what I have, but my array. length returns unchanged.

```
for(let i = 0; i > array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === index) {
      array.splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
  return array;
```

Comment: Well, if there wasn't a single value in `array` that was equal to `index` then, of course, nothing will have changed (apart from the `>` / `<` mistake of course).

Comment: That doesn't really help, bro. I have an array offscreen. I'm trying to write something to remove an object at an index. Also, I'm new to this.

Comment: Carsten did give you a hint.... try logging `i` and `array[i]` to the console for each loop.

Comment: console.log(i, array[i]); like this?

Comment: here's my code. Array is offscreen. I'm trying to remove an object but my console.log(artist.length); keeps returning 20, I'm looking to decrease that value by one.  function removeArtist(array, index) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === index) {
      array[i].splice(i, 0)
    }
  }
  return array;
}
console.log(artists.length);

Comment: kept working at it. here's where I'm at.          [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `function removeArtist(array, index) {
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++){
    if(array[i] === index) {
      array[i].splice(i, 1)
    }
  }
  return array[i];
}
console.log(removeArtist.length);
`

Comment: now removeArtist console.logs 2 when I would like for it to return one. can anyone make some suggestions?

Comment: @toadlyfe  Try logging `console.log( array.indexOf( index))` before the loop to verify `index` is in the array to start with.

Answer (score 0):

omg, I was way overthinking this. Here is my solution.

```
function removeArtist(array){
  return array.splice(12, 1);
}
console.log(removeArtist(artists));
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. If you commented on / explained your solution, you would have noticed that it does declare, but does not use `index`, and `artists` is very, very unexpected and mysterious here.

Comment: @zkoza SO, I see what you are saying. The instructions that I was given told me to "Receive a number which is the desired index in the array" which I now see is the number I put in of the second line. Removing the 'index' doesn't change the output of my code. thank you for pointing that out and helping me learn the correct way to do things!

Comment: Then you might consider editing your answer... Others may come here and wonder "How to remove an element at an index (javascript)".

Comment: @zkoza Done and done. Thank you for your help on this.